# Basics of MRS. Interpretation and constant utility

Tags: utility, marginal

I am sure this question has been asked before but I didn't know what to search for since its a quite long question.

Say, I have a utility function U = sqrt(x)*sqrt(y) and the MRS = y/x.

Say I have y = 4 Bananas and x = 2 apples. Now at this point I would trade 2 bananas for 1 additional apple. OR is it that I am willing to trade two apples for 1 additional banana (?) This always messes me up.

More importantly, if I do exchange, lets say 2 bananas for 1 apple, I end up with 2 Bananas and 3 Apples. However, the utility of this bundle compared to 4 bananas and 2 apples is not the same. This also always messes me up.

I am usually a logically minded person, but somehow I cant wrap my head around the correct interpretation.

I would really appreciate help  with a quick answer or a link to some PAQs.

kind regards